# Jackson deserialization with builder pattern: "Build method has bad return type, not compatible with POJO type"

Tags: java, jackson, mixins, builder, json-deserialization

I have a simple class that uses a builder pattern.

```
public class Foo implements FooInterface {
  .....
  public static final class Builder {
     public Builder setValueA(String value) {...}
     public Builder setValueB(String value) {...}
     public FooInterface build() {...}
  }
}
```

Note that my Builder.build() method actually returns an object of the interface type and not the implemented type. I then mixin annotations (because the class Foo is actually a 3rd party class) for defining the sub types of the interface FooInterface like so:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Foo.class, name = "foo")})
public abstract class FooInterfaceMixin {}
```

And mixin for defining the builder pattern of class Foo, like so:

```
@JsonTypeName("foo")
@JsonDeserialize(builder=Foo.Builder.class)
public abstract class FooMixin {}
```

Finally, to deserialize, I do:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixIn(FooInterface.class, FooInterfaceMixin.class);
mapper.addMixIn(Foo.class, FooMixin.class);

final String jsonString = "{\"type\":\"foo\", \"valueA\":\"a\", \"valueB\":\"b\"}";
FooInterface foo = mapper.readValue(jsonString, FooInterface.class);
```

I get the error ***Build method 'Foo$Builder#build(0 params) has bad return type (FooInterface), not compatible with POJO type (Foo)***

It looks like [this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/BeanDeserializerBuilder.java) is the culprit, but I don't understand why returning a super type in a build method wont be acceptable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a Jackson bug. I've reported an issue:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/761

Comment: Thanks Alexey. That is helpful. Not enough reputation to upvote your response, but thanks.

Comment: Thank you for reporting, fixing the bug! Will be in 2.5.3 once that gets out.